# How to use sum grouped elements using function in model? Laravel - eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am looking for solution to use SUM in eloquent query on grouped elements with use of function in order model.

Here is my query:

```
$orders = Order::selectRaw('year(created_at) year, month(created_at) month, count(id) as ordersPerMonth')
            ->groupBy('year', 'month')
            ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
            ->notDeleted()
            ->get();
```

And it displays total orders number per month:

[image]

And it looks fine but now I need to sum orders total value in given month. In order model I have a function which is returning that value for given order:

```
public function totalValue()
{
    return $this->orderProductsTotal() + $this->carrier_gross;
}
```

This function SUM all products values plus shipping cost.

And question is how to apply this function for above query to get total orders value for given month?

Kind regards for any help.

Comment: include $this->orderProductsTotal()

Comment: provide database structure pls